# problem in editing exisiting moveit package

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using the techman robot tm-700
https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1

I  want to add some pose to the robot so I tried editing using moveit setup assistant. So I selected the directory as /home/akash/project/src/tmr_ros1/tm5_700_moveit_config and selected load files and I got the following error[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381335/problem-in-editing-exisiting-moveit-package/) by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

by simply sourcing the folder the problem was sorted out

---

Originally posted by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) with karma: 32 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0